# How to update a column using active record concurrently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, concurrency

Here're my models - User, UserDevice, Device.

The tables 've the following columns:

users - id, name, email, phone, etc.

devices - id, imei, model etc.

user_devices - id, user_id, device_id etc.

Now I added a new column to devices trk, and want to update it to 1 for  a huge number of users.

Here're how my models look.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_devices
  has_one :some_model
  # ....
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user, through: :user_devices
  attr_accessor :device_user_phone
  # ....

  # some callbacks which depend on on trk & device_user_phone
end

class UserDevice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
  belongs_to :user
  # ....
end
```

The list of user ids are provided in csv file like this:

```
1234
1235
1236
....
```

This's what I tried so far, but it updates one after the other and is taking a lot of time. Also I can't use update_all, as I want the call_backs to be triggered.

```
def update_user_trk(user_id)
  begin
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    user_devices = user.user_devices
    user_devices.each do |user_device|
      user_device.device.update(trk: 1, device_user_col: user.some_model.col) if user_device.device.trk.nil?
    end
  rescue StandardError => e
    Rails.logger.error("ERROR_FOR_USER_#{user_id}::#{e}")
  end
end

def read_and_update(file_path)
  start_time = Time.now.to_i
  unless File.file? file_path
    Rails.logger.error("File not found")
  end
  CSV.foreach(file_path, :headers => false) do |row|
    update_user_trk(row[0])
  end
  end_time = Time.now.to_i
  return end_time-start_time
end
```

Since this updates one row after another in a sequence, it's taking a lot of time and I was wondering if this can be done concurrently to speed it up.

Ruby version : ruby-2.2.3
rails version : Rails 4.2.10

Answer (score 0):

This is at least slightly quicker, this way you're not creating and committing a new transaction on every update.

```
user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
user.user_devices.each do |user_device|
  if user_device.device.trk.nil?
    user_device.device.trk = 1
    user_device.device_user_col = user.some_model.col
  end
end

user.save
```

Comment: Is there any way I can read spped up the reads from csv file - like maybe get the data in batches or something?

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Do you think I can do something about concurrency, so that instead of waiting to update next user after finishing the previous one, I can maybe update a bunch of users at a time?

Comment: Have you taken a look at these gems https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert